# Python - caching a property to avoid future calculations

Tags: python, django, caching, attributes, properties

In the following example, `cached_attr` is used to get or set an attribute on a model instance when a database-expensive property (`related_spam` in the example) is called. In the example, I use `cached_spam` to save queries. I put print statements when setting and when getting values so that I could test it out. I tested it in a view by passing an `Egg` instance into the view and in the view using `{{ egg.cached_spam }}`, as well as other methods on the `Egg` model that make calls to `cached_spam` themselves. When I finished and tested it out the shell output in Django's development server showed that the attribute cache was missed several times, as well as successfully gotten several times. It seems to be inconsistent. With the same data, when I made small changes (as little as changing the print statement's string) and refreshed (with all the same data), different amounts of misses / successes happened. How and why is this happening? Is this code incorrect or highly problematic?

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    ... fields

    @property
    def related_spam(self):
        # Each time this property is called the database is queried (expected).
        return Spam.objects.filter(egg=self).all()  # Spam has foreign key to Egg.

    @property
    def cached_spam(self):
        # This should call self.related_spam the first time, and then return
        # cached results every time after that.
        return self.cached_attr('related_spam')

    def cached_attr(self, attr):
        """This method (normally attached via an abstract base class, but put
        directly on the model for this example) attempts to return a cached
        version of a requested attribute, and calls the actual attribute when
        the cached version isn't available."""
        try:
            value = getattr(self, '_p_cache_{0}'.format(attr))
            print('GETTING - {0}'.format(value))
        except AttributeError:
            value = getattr(self, attr)
            print('SETTING - {0}'.format(value))
            setattr(self, '_p_cache_{0}'.format(attr), value)
        return value
```

Comment: I came up against this annoyance and realised that another way to solve this problem is to use the `with` template tag to create an alias for a calculated result.

Comment: @humble - thx, that's actually a quite helpful note.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, as far as it goes. The problem probably isn't there, but in how you use that code.

The main thing to realise is that model instances don't have identity. That means that if you instantiate an Egg object somewhere, and a different one somewhere else, even if they refer to the same underlying database row they won't share internal state. So calling `cached_attr` on one won't cause the cache to be populated in the other.

For example, assuming you have a RelatedObject class with a ForeignKey to Egg:

```
my_first_egg = Egg.objects.get(pk=1)
my_related_object = RelatedObject.objects.get(egg__pk=1)
my_second_egg = my_related_object.egg
```

Here `my_first_egg` and `my_second_egg` both refer to the database row with pk 1, but they are *not* the same object:

```
>>> my_first_egg.pk == my_second_egg.pk
True
>>> my_first_egg is my_second_egg
False
```

So, filling the cache on `my_first_egg` doesn't fill it on `my_second_egg`.

And, of course, objects won't persist across requests (unless they're specifically made global, which is horrible), so the cache won't persist either.

Comment: thanks. The example provided is, I think, exactly what's going on. I just can't seem to figure out where in my code I'm getting so many instances. One object that should have only 2 separate instances based on my review of the code (one from `my_related_object.egg`) has 4 instances. I think it's time for a complete overhaul of my model; all 200 lines 8(

Comment: I found the culprit! I had a rogue method that was getting all of one object again (my editor's search just didn't find it because the syntax was a bit different due to filtering). With that, combined with my caching (simple memoizing) method and a clever select related I got my 31 queries down to 3!!! Thanks again for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Http servers that scale are shared-nothing; you can't rely on anything being singleton. To share state, you need to connect to a special-purpose service.

Django's [caching support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) is appropriate for your use case. It isn't necessarily a global singleton either; if you use `locmem://`, it will be process-local, which could be the more efficient choice.

Comment: this is just for per-request caching. I would never try to implement my own caching framework. I'm just sick of pulling objects from the database over and over during the same request.